# Set TextView of a Fragment with value generated in another Fragment (NPE)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview, fragment

I have an Activity QuestScreen, which at its creation holds the Fragment *FragmentQuest*.
If i press at the Button, this triggers the *next()* Method of the Screen activity, leading to replace the *FragmentQuest* with *FragmentAction*.

The replacing works so far. The problem is, that after the replace i want to set a TextView in the FragmentAction, to avalue which is generated in the 
QuestScreen Activity.

My first attempt was to set the *TextView* outside the *onCreatView* of  *FragmentAction*. This lead to a Nullpointer exception adressing the TextView.

So far I have looked at: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058049/unable-to-access-view-outside-oncreateview), [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193159/access-fragments-view-from-outside-oncreateview-method), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256255/set-textview-text-from-a-fragment-wont-work) and [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424281/how-to-set-value-for-textview-of-fragment-received-from-another-fragment)

The attempt seen below leads to an NullpointerException marked in the code.

**In The QuestScreen Class**

```
 private void next(){

    //The needed value for the TextView is stored in nextTransition
    Transition nextTransition;
    //Check if an entry is in the list
    if(quest.getTransitionsAbleToFire().size() > 0){
        nextTransition = quest.getTransitionsAbleToFire().get(0);

        fragmentAction = (FragmentAction) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_ACTION);

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (fragmentAction == null) {
            Log.d("QuestScreen onCreate" , "create fAction for first time");
            // add the fragment
            fragmentAction = (FragmentAction) Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentAction.class.getName(), null);

            fm.beginTransaction().add(fragmentAction, TAG_FRAGMENT_ACTION).commit();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, fragmentAction);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        //Triggers the corresponding activity in fragmentAction, to set the TextView to a value which is stored in nextTransition
        fragmentAction.nextAction(nextTransition);
        nextTransition.fire();

    }
    else{
        CharSequence text = "Quest END";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**In the FragmentAction Class**

```
public class FragmentAction extends Fragment {

private TextView txtYourQuest;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // CREATE VIEWS HERE

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_action_fragment, container, false);
    txtYourQuest = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtV_Your_Quest);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public void nextAction(Transition prmTransition){

    // --> Here in the enxt Line comes the NPE :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.flFragmentContainer);
    LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
            .inflate(R.layout.content_action_fragment, container, false);

    txtYourQuest.setText("Your " + prmTransition.getAction().getPosition() + ". is to:\n "
    + prmTransition.getAction().getActionName());
}
```

Comment: @Rotwang - OP basically asks how to pass data to a Fragment and says that previous attempts resulted in various NPEs (one is supposed to demonstrate own effort after all). But as the solution is not "do a null check", IMO  if it's a duplicate at all, then rather of the question to which the last link is referring. Please note this is not about wanting to reopen, I posted the answer because it was too long for a comment, and I upvoted because  it's a well asked question for a newbie on SO. And if I got it right, good duplicates may help others by pointing to the needle in the haystack.

Comment: @0X0nosugar `The attempt seen below leads to an NullpointerException marked in the code.` Enoug to be arked as `Yust Another NPE-Related Duplicate Question`.

Comment: @Rotwang - all right, so if this was my question I should add null checks where necessary and then ask "why is this code not working"?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm expecting you to be an expert developer. Then you're not supposed to fall into an NPE trap. Or if you accidentally do, that you can easily get rid of it. Therefore, you would not need to ask a question.

Comment: @Rotwang - thank you for trusting me to avoid/ handle NPEs ;-) and thank you for your patience. Maybe this is just the point: for me, this is a question about android mechanics, thinly veiled by some NPEs. With null checks the app won't crash. But I suppose "won't crash" is not "mission accomplished".

Comment: Sorry for duplicating, I didn't know.
Played a bit with the code and created a workaround.
Instead of using the _getActivity_ Method, which returns null. (I think because the _nextAction()_ is executed before onCreate, onCreateView, onAttach etc.)
I now store the submitted data in an local object, and use this object to fill the TextView after the _nextAction()_ Method, using it in the _onCreateView_.

Answer (score 0):

> Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

This means your `getActivity()` somehow returns `null`.
To find out, why does this happen, google something like "`getActivity()` returns null". **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)** is a good example of this kind of question on stackoverflow.

And this a workaround to get rid of the crash.

- Add activity field to your fragment.

  Activity activity;
- Override `onAttach()` method and set the value to your `activity` field.

  ```
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      this.activity = activity;
  }
  ```
- Replace `getActivity()` method with your `activity` variable.

FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.flFragmentContainer);

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I have tried to set an global variable as you suggested and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083053/android-fragment-onattach-deprecated).
But it is not working. It seems like the code of nextAction() is executed before the onAttach() method. (At least in my case, all outputs in onAttach are not displayed in the console.)